# Call Flash AS3 function from javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash, actionscript-3, audio

I want a link to trigger a sound click in flash AS3. I've taken the .play() outside of the function to confirm that it works by itself. What am I missing that will let me call an AS3 function from javascript?

**Here is my html**

```
    <object width="5px" height="5px">
        <param name="movie" value="play_coin_sound/playCoin.swf?v=5">
        <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
        <embed src="play_coin_sound/playCoin.swf?v=5" width="5px" height="5px">
    </object>

    <span id="play-sound">Play Sound</span>
```

**Here is my javascript**

```
$('#play-sound').click(function(){ playCoin(); });
```

**Here is my AS3 function**

```
var coinSound:Sound = new Sound();
coinSound.load(new URLRequest("coin.mp3"));

function playCoin() {
    coinSound.play();
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did do ExternalInterface.addCallBack("playCoin",playCoin) ??????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are more comfortable with JavaScript than ActionScript, you could try using SoundManager:

> "By wrapping and extending HTML5 and Flash Audio APIs, SoundManager 2
>   brings reliable cross-platform audio to JavaScript."

http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/

**Edit**: to clarify, SoundManager makes us of Flash when neccessary, like in browsers that don't support HTML5 audio, or if you want to use MP3 in browsers that don't support it.

Comment: I would love to use something like this, but my click sound needs to work in IE's and non html5 compliant browsers.

Comment: With SoundManger, it will. That is the idea of it, to do "reliable cross-platform audio". In non HTML5 browsers, it makes use of Flash instead.

Answer (score 0):

The following blogpost explains how to use the ExternalInterface class to listen for javascript function calls which will trigger AS3 functions. It provides examples of bid-directional communication.

http://www.viget.com/inspire/bi-directional-actionscript-javascript-communication/

Answer (score 0):

This should put you right on track http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/external_interface.html